# express-session won't set cookie connect.sid

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

**EDIT 5**

I have back and front end running on LAMP environment accesible with `192.168.80.213/backend` adress.
I try to make a push notification server using nodejs, socket.io and express framework to link back and front end.

My nodejs server is listening on port `3000` while my backend and front end listenning on port 80 both using apache.

Here is my node client :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io('http://192.168.80.213:3000/');
</script>
```

Here is my node server :

```
const   express          = require('express')
        , app            = express()
        , http           = require('http').Server(app)
        , socketIo       = require('socket.io')(http)
        , cookieParser   = require('cookie-parser')
        , cookie         = require('cookie')
        , connect        = require('connect')
        , expressSession = require('express-session')
        , port           = 3000
        , helmet         = require('helmet')
        , name           = 'connect.sid'
        , sessionStore   = new expressSession.MemoryStore({ reapInterval: 60000 * 10 })
        , sessionSecret  = 'VH6cJa7yZSmkRbmjZW#J3%CDn%dt'
        , environment    = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
        ;

/** Configuration **/
app.enable('trust proxy');
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
    'name'  : name,
    'secret': sessionSecret,
    'store' : sessionStore,
    'resave': true,
    'saveUninitialized': true
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello from node');
});

socketIo.use(function(socket, callback) {
    // Read cookies from handshake headers
    var cookies = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie);
    // We're now able to retrieve session ID
    var sessionID;
    if (cookies[name]) {
        console.log( "cookies['" + name + "'] = " + cookies[name] );
        sessionID = cookieParser.signedCookie( cookies[name], sessionSecret );
        console.log( "sessionID = " + sessionID );
    }else{
        console.log( "cookies['" + name + "'] = undefined" );
    }

    if (!sessionID) {
        console.log('ERROR NO SESSION CONNECTION REFUSED !!');
        callback('No session', false);
    } else {
        // Store session ID in handshake data, we'll use it later to associate
        // session with open sockets
        socket.handshake.sessionID = sessionID;
        callback(null, true);
    }

});


socketIo.on('connection', function (socket) { // New client
    console.log( 'new connection..' );
    console.log('user ' + socket.handshake.sessionID + ' authenticated and is now connected.');  

});

/** Start server */
http.listen(port);
console.log( "listening on :" + port );
```

Go to `192.168.80.213:3000` and see 'Hello from node' and cookie['connect.sid'] is set according to screenshot below

[image: connect.sid cookie correctly set]

And console output :

[image]

Now Clearing cache and i'm going to my back end app where is my nodeClient `192.168.80.213/backend`.

connect.sid cookie doesn't exist

[image]

And console output :

[image]

Why express-session ain't set cookie.sid ? how can i fix that ? I'm new to node and express, i spend many times googling without succes, hope some node masters coul help me !!

regards

Answer (score 1):

I dont know which version of socket.io you are using but after version 1.0 (`> 1.0`):

- To register a middleware you should use `socketIo.use` (See [documentation](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace))
- First parameter is *incoming socket* which have access to request through `socket.request`
- express session by default save cookies with `connect.sid` name if you want to use `io` name you should set it explicitely (See [name option](https://github.com/expressjs/session#name))
- When you want to parse a signed cookie you should provide it `sessionSecret` not `sessionStore`
- and finally i think handshake support is deprecated and you should attach anything you want directly to **socket** (See [authentication-differences](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#authentication-differences)).

With considering aboves you could use a middleware like following to `Authenticate` your sockets:

```
// every incoming socket should pass this middleware
socketIo.use(function(socket, next) {
  var cookies = cookie.parse(socket.request.headers.cookie);
  var sessionID = cookieParser.signedCookie(cookies['connect.sid'], sessionSecret);
  sessionStore.get(sessionID, function(err, session) {
    if ( session && session.isAuthenticated ) {
      socket.userId = session.user.id;
      return next();
    } else {
      return next(new Error('Not Authenticated'));
    }
  });
});
// when connected ...
socketIo.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('user ' + socket.userId + ' authenticated and is now connected.')
});
```

Here i consider you set `isAuthenticated` Boolean value and `user` on session when users logged in.

Also bear in mind that built in `sessionStore`, MemoryStore is not suit for production environment:

> The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is purposely not
>   designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most
>   conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for
>   debugging and developing.

So you must consider using another session store like:

- [connect-mongo](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo)

  or
- [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis)

Comment: console.log( cookies['connect.sid'] ); output undefined, then console.log( cookies['io'] ); return something why cookies['connect.sid'] is undefined ?

Comment: Whit just this code it's hard to find out from where that `io` cookie comes in. Is there anywhere you might set that cookie?

Comment: What do you need? All my server side code is above and i'm sure that i don't set any cookie anywhere

Comment: remove `connect = require('connect')` you dont need it. also disable `helmet` maybe its preventing setting cookies. and test again.

Comment: done !! not working... :'( connect.sid still undefined.. client side commented all lines except `var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');`

Comment: For infos here is my console output `listening on :3000
io=JzJqLbaa6K1-hbPoAAAB
cookies [object Object]
cookies["connect.sid"] = undefined
undefined
error Not authentified`

Comment: remove your browser cache and test again. i really got no idea where and how that `io` cookie has been set.

Comment: remove cache not working either :/ i'm on it since 2 days without succes..damn

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience using cookie or cookie-parser and am generally new to node, but I had a similar system to authenticate socket connections by accessing server side session variables if that helps at all.

Save the session details inside a variable

```
var sessionStorage = expressSession({
'secret': sessionSecret,
'store' : sessionStore,
'resave': true,
'saveUninitialized': true 
});
```

let socketIo and app use the storage

```
socketIo.use(function (socket, next) {
    sessionStorage(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});
app.use(sessionStorage);
```

and then inside on connect you can access those session variables using:

```
socket.request.res.session.[variable name]
```

Comment: the point is that by default express creates a cookie named `connect.sid`. In my case it doesn't do it

Comment: Checking debugger "socket.request.session" has an "id" property, note its not "sid". This seems to match up with the cookie set in the browser.

Comment: there is no id property inside `socket.request.session` but `socket.request.sessionID` is present but is not matching with cookie set in the browser

Comment: Check the entire string. I noticed the first 5 or so characters was trimmed off the variable when accessing it from the server